# Bring Your Own Key (BYOK) - Configure Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption

Before having configured the DB encryption with BYOK (Bring your own key) it is possible to work, develop and configure on MC or it is not possible to do anything before having done DB encryption with BYOK (Bring your own key)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

BYOK functionality is for accounts with TDE and must be enabled on brand new accounts. Initial key is generated by Marketing Cloud, so your database is already encrypted and you can use your account.
With [BYOK release](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_january_2021_setup_byok_ga.htm&type=5) you can replace existing key with your own key.